# Import settings from other file into config.txt

Tags: config.txt

Is it possible to import settings from another file into config.txt?

### As I imagine

config.txt example content:

```
...

# Uncomment this to enable the lirc-rpi module
#dtoverlay=lirc-rpi
# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README
# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

...

include="/home/pi/mysettings.txt"
```

### Why I want to do that

I mount the boot partion readonly. Sometimes I need to change some settings.

---

So I have to:

1. modify fstab (make boot partionen writeable)
2. restart
3. change config.txt
4. restart, test settings, maybe back to 3.
5. modify fstab (make readonly)
6. restart
7. done

---

What I want to do:

1. change mysettings.txt
2. restart, test settings, maybe back to 1.
3. done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. [Dokumentation of config.txt](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/README.md) says:

> This (rem.: config.txt) is read by the GPU before the ARM CPU and Linux are initialised.
>   It must therefore be located on the first (boot) partition of your SD
>   card, alongside bootcode.bin and start.elf.

**edit:** But on Raspbian you can simply remount the partition `read/write`:

```
pi ~$ sudo mount -o remount,rw /boot
```

Do your work, then remount the partition back to `read only`:

```
pi ~$ sudo mount -o remount,ro /boot
```

Comment: Can you please accept this answer by clicking the check on the left side of it? It would help me a little bit ;-)

Comment: I was about to click the check mark, but I still have hope that someone has a good idea. Or maybe another solution that works in a similar way

Comment: @maddin1502 had another look at your problem because I have overseen the very simple solution. Have updated the answer.